# Normalize XLabel on NDVI Index chart in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart, google-earth-enterprise

I'm using the "ui.Chart.Image.Regions" type to produce three graphics for three different SENTINEL-2 images, with EVI index values.

I would like to normalize the horizontal label (the X label) so they look the same on all three graphs.

I used the "xLabels" property of this chart type by putting the values `xLabels = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],`

however I got the following error message:

> Error generating chart: The length of the xLabels list should equal
>   the number of bands in the image. Found 1 bands and 3 elements in
>   xLabels. ".

Here is my code: [EVI INDEX](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f1144d98ee33509b2db9f8789bbc110c)

Answer (score 1):

They look the same on the horizontal axis. I guess you want to set predefined vertical labels? You can set that under setOptions({vAxis}) as follows:

```
vAxis: {maxValue: 1, ticks: [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]}
```

[Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e3f2196ed2061a1dc17f1bfb979eaa37)

Comment: Its done and work, thanks so much